# Restoring backed-up Docker volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, backup, restore, docker-volume

due to hardware problem, I had to replace my small home server with a new one.
Several self-hosted services with Docker were running on the server for which I tried to backup the volumes following the [instructions on the official Docker website](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) and those present in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEy8iFbgbPA&t=451s) and in this [cheat-sheet](https://github.com/xcad2k/cheat-sheets/blob/main/infrastructure/docker/docker.md). Now, following the same documentation, I am trying to restore the backups but without success. The first one I'm trying for is a stack for Nginx Proxy Manager built with Docker compose with this docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  app:
    image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "81:81"
    environment:
      DB_MYSQL_HOST: "db"
      DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_MYSQL_NAME: "db_name"
      DB_MYSQL_USER: "db_user"
      DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "db_password"
    volumes:
      - data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: jc21/mariadb-aria:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "db_name"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root_password"
      MYSQL_USER: "db_user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "db_password"
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db:
  data:
```

After starting the stack with `docker compose up -d` command I'm trying to restore db and data volumes with:

- `docker run --rm --volumes-from nginx-proxy-manager-db-1 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd / && tar xvf /backup/nginx-proxy-manager_db_20220717-082200.tar --strip 1"`
- `docker run --rm --volumes-from nginx-proxy-manager-app-1 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd / && tar xvf /backup/nginx-proxy-manager_data_20220717-082200.tar --strip 1"`

What's wrong?